# No module named 'pymongo'

Tags: python, pymongo

I have both python 3.5 and 2.7. When I use the code `import pymongo` in pycharm, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "/home/tian/PycharmProjects/untitled/ing.py", line 1, in
 <module>    
import pymongo    
ImportError: No module named 'pymongo'
```

Now I have installed pymongo in both python2.7 and python 3.5 but it still doesn't work.

```
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"

3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
 [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

$ python -c "import pymongo; print(pymongo.version);
    print(pymongo.has_c())"

3.6.0
    True
```

Comment: First run `python -m pip install pymongo` on your console then try.

Comment: It returns：“Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo-3.6.0-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg”  and still not works.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal run

```
which python | pbcopy
```

Then open PyCharm, go to **Preferences** > **Project (*project name*)** > **Project Interpreter**.

Paste the contents of your clipboard in "Python Interpreter" field.

[image: Pycharm Screenshot]